# How can I send stream messages from chat gpt in aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, openai-api, aiogram

How can I send stream messages in aiogram? I have tried this, there's no an error, but doesn't work

```
async def send_message_stream(self, prompt, dialog_messages=[]):
    answer = None
    dialog_messages += [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    while answer is None:
      if self.model in {"gpt-3.5-turbo", "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k", "gpt-4"}:
            response = await client.chat.completions.create(
                model=self.model,
                messages=dialog_messages,
                stream=True
                )
            answer = ""
            async for item in response:
                delta = item.choices[0].delta
                if "content" in delta:
                    answer += delta.content
                    yield answer.strip()




@router.message()
async def generate_text(msg: Message):
    response = chatbot.send_message_stream(prompt, dialog_messages)
    async for item in response:
        await msg.edit_text(item, disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

nothing happens